# Display notification with the app in the foreground

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, notifications

I have an iOS flutter app and I want to display a local notification when the app is in the foreground.

The code I'm going to paste works if the app is in the background, but not when it is open.

Create the notification:

```
        // Create notification content
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = title
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        
        // Set trigger
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 2, repeats: false)
        
        // Submit request
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        
        center.add(request) { (error : Error?) in
            if let theError = error {
                print(theError.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

In the method:

```
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
}
```

I am adding the following, driven by other responses to this same problem:

```
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        }
```

None of the above works. The notification is not displayed if the app is in the foreground.

What should I do to display the local notification even if the app is in the foreground?

Comment: You have to show your own toast or UI in response to receiving a notification when your app is in the foreground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS the system does not automatically display notifications that are delivered while your app is running in the foreground.

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app)

> If your app is in the foreground, the system delivers the notification to your app for handling.

You need to implement the [`userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter) delegate function and call the provided completion handler with the desired presentation option, probably [`.banner`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationpresentationoptions/3564812-banner)

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
                         willPresent notification: UNNotification, 
               withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.banner)
}
```

You will need to establish your Notification Center delegate in an appropriate place, such as `didFinishLaunching`